# Access a SQL Server 2005 Express Edition from a network computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

How do you access a SQL Server 2005 Express Edition from a application in a network computer?

The access I need is both from application (Linq-to-SQL and ODBC) and from Management Studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this KB Article. [How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277).
Oh, and remember that the SQLServer name will probably be MyMachineName\SQLExpress

Comment: For  me, the missing step was "Turn on the SQL Server Browser service."

Answer (score 1):

If you're running it on a 2k3 box, you need to install all updates for Sql Server and the 2003 server.

Check the event logs after you start the Sql Server.  It logs everything well, telling you if its being blocked, and where it is listening for connections.

From a remote machine, you can use telnet to see if a sql server is listening for remote connections.  You just need the IP and the port of the server (default is 1433).  From the command line:

```
telnet 192.168.10.10 1433
```

If you get a blank screen, its listening.  If you get thrown back to the command prompt, something is blocking you.